# Gradient effect for Line Graph in iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, gradient, linegraph

I'm trying to generate a graph with gradient/shading effect.  Now I'm able to draw line graph and applied gradient effect to that graph.  It is applying to whole view not to the graph. Now I'm getting image like [image] this.  But I want like[image] this.  I want gradient effect just under the graph.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

The code that I'm using is:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.graphView.frame.size);
[graphView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.graphView.frame.size.width, self.graphView.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 225, 48, 48, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 225, 225, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

float xCordinate, yCordinate;

for (int i = 0; i < [graphValues count]; i++) {
    int val = [[graphValues objectAtIndex: i] intValue] / 5;
    float diff = [[graphValues objectAtIndex: i] floatValue] / 5 - val;
    yCordinate = val * 120 + 120 * diff;
    xCordinate = graphWidth * i / [graphValues count] + 60;
    if (i == 0) 
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), xCordinate, graphHeight + 60 - yCordinate);
    else 
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), xCordinate, graphHeight + 60 - yCordinate);
}
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), xCordinate, graphHeight + 60);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 60, graphHeight + 60);
CGContextClosePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); 
CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextDrawPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGPathStroke);
```

//  CGContextFillPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

```
CGContextClip(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


//Draw Gradient
UIColor *topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.0];
CGColorRef colorRef[] = { [topColor CGColor], [bottomColor CGColor] };
CFArrayRef colors = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void**)colorRef, sizeof(colorRef) / sizeof(CGColorRef), &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, NULL);
CFRelease(colorSpace);
CFRelease(colors);

//  Draw a linear gradient from top to bottom
CGPoint gradStartPoint = CGPointMake(50.0, graphView.bounds.size.height);
CGPoint gradEndPoint = CGPointMake(50.0, 0.0);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), gradient, gradStartPoint, gradEndPoint, 0);

CFRelease(gradient);

// Cleanup
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

graphView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: If you want the full red (or white) color to be at the topmost point on the graph, not the top of the view, you need to specify the y co-ordinate of the highest point in the graph as the top of the gradient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to set a clipping path before you draw the gradient. See the CGContextRef docs for details.

Comment: Thank you,  but I'm using clipping path. CGContextClip(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());   But the current context is defined with the back image view.UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.graphView.frame.size);
 [graphView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.graphView.frame.size.width, self.graphView.frame.size.height)];

Comment: @MohanVydehi: Are you saying that you're setting the clipping path in a different context from the one you draw the image into? If so, that's why. Otherwise, it would clarify things greatly if you'd edit your question to include the full code of whatever method of your view is doing the clipping and drawing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I understood the problem.  I attached my code please make some changes and help me to finish the application.